# Why is Rails using the default debug_exception_response_format in test mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Given that I've set the following in config/environments/test.rb (I know I don't need to, but I just want to be certain):

```
config.debug_exception_response_format = :api
```

Why are exceptions triggered by my Cucumber features coming back as HTML?

```
When the admin attempts to create a new vendor # features/step_definitions/vendor_steps.rb:9                                                              
  743: unexpected token at '<!DOCTYPE html>                                                                                                               
  <html lang="en">                                                                                                                                        
  <head>                                                                                                                                                  
    <meta charset="utf-8" />                                                                                                                              
    <title>Action Controller: Exception caught</title>                                                                                                    
    <style>                                                                                                                                               
      body {                                                                                                                                              
        background-color: #FAFAFA;                                                                                                                        
        color: #333;                                                                                                                                      
        margin: 0px;                                                                                                                                      
      }
```

Shouldn't I be getting JSON back in this case or am I misunderstanding something?

EDIT:

Per some of the comments below, I've verified that the `Content-Type` is `application/json` and that `config.debug_exception_response_format` is configured correctly in development and staging environments. Unfortunately, I'm still seeing this issue.

From within the affected controller:

> (byebug) request.headers["Content-Type"]
>   "application/json"

Comment: Was your request an API request? It seems to me it was an HTML request.

Comment: That's a good question. It _should_ have been an API request, as my understanding is that this application only runs in `api` mode. I will try manually setting the headers in Rack::Test and seeing if that has any affect, though.

Comment: @ZhongZheng I tried explicitly setting `Content-Type: application/json` in the Rack::Test request but, inexplicably, that led to the request being submitted as URL encoded form parameters and led to a parse error in my controller. Regardless, I was working under the assumption that Rails, running in API mode, would _never_ return HTML.

Comment: @pdoherty926 do you have a link to full html ?. That looks like a Rails exception HTML page which has inline css.

Comment: By link, do you mean the entire output? Regardless, you're right - that's exactly what I'm seeing. I'm just not sure why ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this inside of your **config/environments/development.rb** as well.

```
config.debug_exception_response_format = :api
```

Even if you are running your application in api mode, if your application was created as a default rails application then your development exception response will run in the default format response of rendering HTML/XHR.

**EDIT:**

Can you try adding the following test helpers?

```
def api_get action, params={}, version="1"
  get "/api/v#{version}/#{action}", params
  JSON.parse(response.body) rescue {}
end

def api_post action, params={}, version="1"
  post "/api/v#{version}/#{action}", params
  JSON.parse(response.body) rescue {}
end

def api_delete action, params={}, version="1"
  delete "/api/v#{version}/#{action}", params
  JSON.parse(response.body) rescue {}
end

def api_put action, params={}, version="1"
  put "/api/v#{version}/#{action}", params
  JSON.parse(response.body) rescue {}
end
```

Did you take the byebug breakpoint out to ensure that it doesn't have anything to do with that gem?

Comment: I'll try this when I get a minute. Though, I should mention that this was never a vanilla Rails application.

Comment: This problem can also occur if you have the _web-console_ gem installed.

Comment: I do not have that gem installed.

Comment: As mentioned above, I'm now explicitly setting this value in environments/test.rb and environments/development.rb and still seeing the HTML response.

Answer (score 0):

`config.debug_exception_response_format = :api`

means

> To render debugging information preserving the response format, use
>   the value :api.

[Rails doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html#changing-an-existing-application)

Given this is a feature spec for admin, therefore the request is very likely to be a HTML request, so the response will also be in HTML format.

**Edit**

Even your request format is explicitly set as json, you still need to explicitly define the response format to be json. Because without defining the response format explicitly something like the following, it would still be in HTML format regardless the request type.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html ...
  format.json ...
end
```

or

```
render json: {hello: 'world'}
```

Comment: I've updated my answer. The request is _definitely_ using `Content-Type: application/json`.

Comment: as you replied previously, `that led to the request being submitted as URL encoded form parameters and led to a parse error in my controller.` is this parse error in json format or HTML format?

Comment: I've now got Rack::Test sending the correcting Content-Type and the params are being parsed without issue. I'm explicitly raising the exception which is triggering this HTML response in my controller via `fail "Hello, SO"`, which is presented in the response body like so: `... <div class=\"line active\">    fail &quo
t;Hello, SO&quot;\n</div> ...`

Comment: It still sounds to me that the response format is in HTML. Even though you changed the request type, it does not necessarily change the response format. You might need to explicitly define it to esponse with json format, given it currently response in HTML format. Usually in a `respond_to` block.   or something like `render json: { hello: 'so'}`

Comment: 1) The HTML is _only_ returned in the case of an uncaught exception. 2) Does API mode not explicitly set the default response type to JSON somewhere? If not, that would be very surprising. I mean, even if that wasn't the case, wouldn't `config.debug_exception_response_format` do that just as well?

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, I assumed this `When the admin attempts to create a new vendor` spec is in HTML format, otherwise there would be a front-end application to consume the API. Could you confirm that the ancestors of the controller being tested inherits from `ActionController::API` instead of `ActionController::Base`?

Comment: Apologies if there was any confusion, but this is most definitely an API application. From my application_controller.rb: `class ApplicationController < ActionController::API; end`. Do you have a link to anything regarding "spec format" as it relates to Cucumber? Perhaps there's some configuration there that I'm unaware of.

Comment: I understood this is an API application, Could you confirm the controller where you raise the exception inherits from the decedents of ApplicationController? It is possible that it inherits from a non-api controller.

Comment: Yes, the controller in question extends ApplicationController.